# passing a type casted pointer to pthread_join

Tags: c, casting, pthreads

I have an assignment where I'm using threads in C, and similar to a lot of people I got errors caused by `pthread_join`'s second argument being of type `void**` , then after some research I figured out how type casting works. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *callback(void *arg){
    sleep(2);
    pthread_exit("done !!\n");
}

int main(){
  pthread_t th;
  void *val;

  pthread_create(&th, NULL, callback, NULL);
  pthread_join(th, &val);
  printf("%s", (char*)val);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and this worked as expected, but then I got curious and tried to declare a `char *val` then pass the casted version of it to the `pthread_join` function, like this:

```c
int main(){
  pthread_t th;
  char *val;

  pthread_create(&th, NULL, callback, NULL);
  pthread_join(th, (void*)&val);
  printf("%s", val);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This worked fine, but I don't understand how the type casting works in this version of the code. Can anyone explain this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code is correct, and the 2nd code is incorrect. You'll get away with that because the representations for `char *` and `void *` are most likely compatible.

An explicit pointer cast in C almost always says: "I am going to do some really dirty tricks, trust me, I know better than you, dear compiler, what I am doing". There are only 4 exceptions that come to mind where a cast is necessary and right:

- casting to a character pointer or character/void pointer back to the original
- casting a pointer to a struct to the pointer to the type of the initial member or vice versa
- casting a pointer to an union having the original type as its member
- casting a pointer to a function to another function pointer type

All other cases are asking for nasal demons. Rule of thumb with casts is: "the less the better".

Furthermore, the type expected by `pthread_join` is `void **` and not `void *` as was produced by your cast, but the `void *` being a generic pointer is silently converted to the `void **` expected by `pthread_join`.

Comment: Further, the aspect of `pthread_join`'s interface that OP has encountered is an explicit *anti-pattern* that actively encourages the kind of bug/UB in the second version. Generic-type (`void *`) pointers should always be *returned as the return value of a function*, not via pointer-to-pointer arguments where the programmer is tempted to cast to avoid an annoying intermediate variable.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE agree. However `pthread_join` does return an error code, which  no one is ever checking

Comment: Not a very useful one. The only documented error is a "may fail" that can only occur due to programming error, and it's specifically documented that it must not fail with `EINTR`. So there's questionable value to checking the return value.

Comment: @R.. GitHub STOP HELPING ICE, RRe "*The only documented error is a "may fail" that can only occur due to programming error*", huh? [This](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) lists three ways it can fail that aren't programming error.

Comment: Linux pthreads do support more documented error cases for those that POSIX leaves unspecified